# OnClick of button, Increase div it giving dynamic ID to each field in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scenario where a User on `button` click can add upto `12` div's with same `HTML`. The html for the same is as below

```
<div id="dvNPEAddData">
  <div id="dvNPEInnerData">
    <label>Terminated route name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtTerRouteName" />

    <label>Cable Type</label>
    <select id="ddlCableType">
            <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
      <option value="G652">G652</option>
      <option value="G655">G655</option>
        </select>

    <label>Cable Size</label>
    <select id="ddlCableSize">
            <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
            <option value="12F">12F</option>
            <option value="24F">24F</option>
            <option value="48F">48F</option>
    </select>

    <label>No of Live Fibre</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNoLiveFibre" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And the button is also below on which of the above whole div will get created again with dynamic **ID's**

```
<label>ADD NPE +</label>
<input type="button" id="btnAddNPE" value="Add NPE" onclick="addNPEInfo()" />
```

So for that I tried something like below..!

```
var div = document.getElementById('dvNPEInnerData'),
    clone = div.cloneNode(true);
 clone.id = "dvNPEInnerData1";
 //document.body.appendChild(clone);
 document.getElementById('dvNPEAddData').appendChild(clone);
```

The divs are generated properly, but the issue is the `ID` for each control like `input = text` and `select` is not been generated.

> So how should I use this so that it can generate same html with dynamic `ID's`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
var appendNewId=1;
function addNPEInfo(){
    if(appendNewId>12){
        alert("Maximum 12 rows allowed");
        return;
    }
    var div = document.getElementById('dvNPEInnerData'),
    clone = div.cloneNode(true); 

    appendId(clone, "div", appendNewId);
    appendId(clone,"select", appendNewId);
    appendId(clone,"input", appendNewId);
    appendId(clone,"label", appendNewId);

    clone.id = "dvNPEInnerData"+appendNewId;
    //document.body.appendChild(clone);
    document.getElementById('dvNPEAddData').appendChild(clone);
    appendNewId++;
}
function appendId(clone,tag, id){
    var ele = clone.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    for(i in ele){
        ele[i].id = ele[i].id+id;
    }
}
```

Change value of **appendNewId** as per your need.

Comment: I guess we are almost there, this is what it generated. The inner div id is not incrementing. have a look at generated html https://jsfiddle.net/x4bca5py/

Comment: @BNN, I extract **appendNewId** as global, could you please check with new code ?

Comment: its perfect now, one more thing here. I want user to restrict till 12 divs. so how should I stop and prompt a message that you can add more than 12 div's

Comment: inside **addNPEInfo** check the value of **appendNewId** if it is >= 12 then show alert box, and return.

Comment: yeah, can u update with it so that I can accept it as an answer :)

Comment: @BNN, Hi I made changes.

Comment: It, is adding till 13.. :( may be because one is  by default on load

Comment: Thanks Alpesh, for quick and wonderful solution. Will ask more related to this as how to delete any div if wanted by user. Will be needing your help Mate. Thanku so much for the answer :)

Comment: Alpesh, can you help me with the saving logic in javascript.. ? Please

Comment: I would suggest post another question, with your auto generated HTML and JS code

Comment: hi,if you want more info we can chat here and discuss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167715/discussion-between-alpesh-jikadra-and-bnn).

Comment: hi alpesh can u come on chat here.. need to discuss a small thing https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167715/discussion-between-alpesh-jikadra-and-bnn